# How do you view the bottom of really tall cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When there are very tall cells in Microsoft Excel, trying to scroll via mouse or even via scrollbar (clicking on "<-" "->" pointers) just jumps below to the next cell, hiding the bottom content of the large cell in question.

Is there an option to have Excel scroll smoothly?

So far I found only one way - click middle button on mouse - and scroll smoothly by moving mouse aside.

Comment: its not possible . its bug  in excel 2007 if you are using vista

Comment: Yes, I'm on Vista now. And no Fixes available???

Comment: FYI same issue/bug in OpenOffice calc, see this: http://qa.openoffice.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=7722 and this http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&p=86184 It's a nightmare!

Comment: FWIW, this is a usability issue with _every_ version of Excel that I have ever used, and on various OS versions through the years.

Comment: I tend to click and drag the vertical scrollbar in this situation. It's not ideal as I have to hold the mouse button down to prevent it jumping around to "snap to cell" while reading, but I find it easier to control than the middle-mouse-button-drag technique.

Comment: If you - like me - would like this feature to be implemented, feel free to have a look at the corresponding [Excel Feature Request](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/9769824-have-excel-scroll-better-when-there-are-large-cell) and maybe vote for it. (The Excel team said they would base implementation speed on received votes.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is more of a design flaw in Excel than a bug. It's definitely a usability problem as it is super easy to scroll past a cell with it basically never showing in the view.

As much as I hate to suggest this (I *hate* this feature) you can middle-drag to scroll smoothly. Once you release/click again/move the mouse over top of the origin, Excel will snap the top of the view again.

This same problem is present in Office 2010 under Windows 7.

Comment: +1 for the solution. How do you middle-click/drag **on a mac** though?

Comment: You might have luck using a PC mouse and making sure nothing is taking over the middle mouse button (like expose/mission control/dashboard)

Comment: I'm genuinely at a loss to why this is a built in feature *that cannot be turned off*. Fair enough, it might be useful for simple spreadsheets, but users always have large cells that they might want to scroll partly into view using the scroll bars but you can't do it. It's ridiculous!

Comment: Excel's rendering code is *highly* optimized and extremely old. I imagine it is a total mess and re-writing it is not an option. Since it has snapped from the beginning, it continues to have that restriction.

Comment: Charlie, that would make sense if it was impossible to scroll smoothly, but it's not a problem with the rendering engine, because clearly you can scroll smoothly with middle mouse button.  It's not like the grid is ridgidly fixed in the upper left and they're just shifting cell contents into that static grid.  The middle mouse button smooth scrolling proves that's not the issue.  This is simply a design flaw, in that the scrollbars always force it to jump to the next cell.  The behavior could easily be switched off, they just don't make it an option.

Comment: Triynko, do you have any evidence to support your claim? One of the Mac office devs has/had a blog and wrote about these sorts of issues: http://www.schwieb.com/blog. The smooth scrolling with the middle mouse button may depend on a hack that breaks something like focus. Middle mouse scrolling actually only works vertically, it still skips around when scrolling horizontally. If this would be a simple code change, this would already have been implemented. It's certainly caused by *extremely* complicated rendering code that can't be cheaply rewritten.

Comment: This problem lies in all Excel versions as well as other speadsheet tools I've ever used and it's really annoying

Comment: how to do it in `libre-office-calc`?

Comment: I would ask another question; this is for Excel.

Comment: If you - like me - would like this feature to be implemented, feel free to have a look at the corresponding [Excel Feature Request](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/9769824-have-excel-scroll-better-when-there-are-large-cell) and maybe vote for it. (The Excel team said they would base implementation speed on received votes.)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Excel 2010, Windows 7, and middle-dragging still scrolls one line at a time. Better than the default 3 lines at a time that I get with the mousewheel, but still not what I call "smooth".

Comment: Fabio, are you using any unusual mouse drivers? Can you capture a screenshot of the cursor when you do this?

Answer (score 9):

This is a limitation of excel.
2 options...

1. Change your cell height manually.  Right click on the row number on the left side, choose row height.  Don't use enormous cells.
2. If it's only one cell, don't use one big cell, but instead merge a large # of cells vertically using "merge and center".  This will allow a smooth scroll in relation to that newly merged cell.

Comment: I can't believe Excel and Calc have such a limitation. All my thoughts go to people needing these pieces of software on a daily basis...

Comment: indeed, it's a pain in the ***.

Answer (score 7):

You won't be able to not scroll by rows, but you can minimize them to one row.  Just change the mousewheel setting to 1, as per [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/win_mouse_change_scrolling.mspx?mfr=true).

If you use the <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> button then using the arrow keys will move the screen instead of the cursor.

Comment: Scroll lock has the same limitation, unfortunately.

Comment: +1 As you said, this does not address the issue and quite frankly renders the mouse wheel useless in other applications, but at least Excel no longer skips rows when I set the number of lines to 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can also insert two blank rows between your large rows, then hide the blank rows.  This will make excel act as though you changed your mouse line scroll to 1 line but not affect your other applications.  This might not solve your entire need (if one large row doesn't even fit on one screen), but it will help a little.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this change in Control Panel > Mouse settings.

To change the number of lines that you scroll in Excel:

1. Open Mouse in Control Panel.
2. On the Wheel tab, under Scrolling, click Scroll, and then select the number of lines to scroll with each notch on the wheel

In Windows 7, mine was set to 3 cells as default, and I was able to change this to 2 (or you can change it to 1 or any number).  I guess the only constraint is that this will affect how the mouse works in ALL programmes.

Comment: same answer as Lance Roberts' from 3 years ago

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to zoom out slightly to 90%, this seems to turn off the "feature" in Excel 2016 at least.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Excel 2016 on PC. At 90% zoom, Excel still "snaps" to the nearest cell if I let go of the scroll bar when the middle of the cell is lined up with the top of the screen.

Comment: This doesn't actually fix it. It just makes the cells small enough that it isn't as annoying.

Answer (score -1):

Quick fix: right click on the column header and select:

[image: Excel_column_width]

Comment: I assume you meant to click on the row header and select Row Height, but then? Change it? To something smaller? Then I won't see the content of the cell anymore and have gained nothing.

Comment: @cdonner This can be done with rows also, yes. The 'gain' is that by decreasing the width of the column it is _now_ (after shrinking) possible to decrease the size of the column further _with a mouse_ (by just dragging the edge of the column) and thus at least partially see/scroll through _multiple_ columns on the screen. The solution doesn't really implement smooth scrolling, that's why I've called it the _quick_ fix.

Answer (score -2):

See if you are able to scroll smoothly in other applications with the middle wheel. This will help determine if the problem is with Excel or your mouse.

If you can't scroll smoothly in other programs, you may want to check your mouse driver settings, update the driver, or both.

Comment: -1 for an answer so useless that I would expect to find it on a Microsoft forum, but not here.