# How to disable snap/jump scrolling in Excel 2016 for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm desparately looking for a way to disable snap-scrolling in Excel 2016 for Mac. Basically as you scroll Excel will continually try to keep the cell you're focused on in the centered. So when you're working on a large spreadsheet and try scrolling up/down, Excel will snap you back. To say it's infuriating is an understatement - I'm close to downgrading.

Comment: yes same issue for me. Very annoying this is the first link I clicked searching for an answer though

Comment: Looks like this has already been answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/47908/enable-smooth-scrolling-in-excel-for-large-cells) and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/how-can-i-disable-jump-to-column-scrolling/9b5f7b12-3d72-41b5-9f13-527fc1e99e78?db=5) as not being possible...

Comment: @JeremyS., if I'm reading correctly, the ones you link to are about Excel only scrolling in whole-cell increments, whereas the OP says Excel isn't scrolling at all--it's snapping back to where he is.

Comment: @MathieuK.: you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was fixed.

https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304933-excel-for-mac/suggestions/10196106-fix-broken-scrolling-in-excel-for-mac

Please confirm.

Comment: I still have this issue, not fixed at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I upgraded by office from 2014 to 2017.
Now I have office 2017 [version 15.33 (170409)] and I can scroll by pixels using Mouse as well as Laptop trackpad. I am using MacOS Sierra version 10 operating system.

Comment: (1) I’m not sure this is what the question is really about.   (2) You say that you “*can* scroll by pixels”.  Did this happen automatically, or did you have to do something to enable it?

Comment: It happens automatically. You dont have to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the window on full-size.  Press the Green Page Size button (top-left beside the yellow one.  Resize to a slightly smaller window.  Worked like a charm.